# How to send TShape object created dynamic to background

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-6

I create some `TShape` objects dynamically (squares on the picture) and now I want to send these objects to the background. The circle must be on the top. How can I do that?

```
void TForm1::spawn_candy()
{
    for (int i = 1;i<=runda;i++)
    {
        candy1[0] = new TShape(candy);
        p_wys = (rand()%90);
        p_szer = (rand()%114);
        candy1[0]->Top = (p_wys*5)+60;
        candy1[0]->Left = p_szer*5;
        Label2->Caption = candy1[0]->Left;
        candy1[0]->Parent = Form1;
        candy1[0]->Width = 30;
        candy1[0]->Height = 30;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All [`TControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl) descendants, including [`TShape`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TShape), have public [`BringToFront()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.BringToFront) and [`SendToBack()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.SendToBack) methods.